# change name of file in nested folders

Tags: linux, bash, awk, rename, file-rename

I have been trying to think of a way to rename file names that are listed in nested folders and am having an issue resolving this matter. as a test i have been able to cut out what part of the name i would like to alter but can't think of how to put that into a variable and chain the name together. the file format looks like this.

```
XXX_XXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_100426151653-all.mp3
```

i have been testing this format out to cut the part out i was looking to change but i am not sure this would be the best way of doing it.

echo XXX_XXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_100426095135-all.mp3 |awk -F_ '{print $4}' | cut -c 1-6

I would like to change the     100426151653 to this     20100426-151653 format in the name.

i have tried to use the rename the file with this command with this format    's/ //g' but that format did not work i had to resort to rename ' ' '' file name to remove a blank space.

so the file would start as this
    XXX_XXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_100426151653-all.mp3
and end like this 
    XXX_XXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_20100426-151653-all.mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using find and a bash function

```
#!/bin/bash

modfn () {
  suffix=$2
  fn=$(basename $1)
  path=$(dirname $1)

  fld1=$(echo $fn | cut -d '_' -f1)
  fld2=$(echo $fn | cut -d '_' -f2)
  fld3=$(echo $fn | cut -d '_' -f3)
  fld4=$(echo $fn | cut -d '_' -f4)
  fld5=${fld4%$suffix}
  l5=${#fld5}
  fld6=${fld5:0:$(($l5 - 6))}
  fld7=${fld5:$(($l5 - 6)):6}

  newfn="${fld1}_${fld2}_${fld3}_20${fld6}-${fld7}${suffix}"

  echo "moving ${path}/${fn} to ${path}/${newfn}"
  mv ${path}/${fn} ${path}/${newfn}"
}


export -f modfn

suffix="-all.mp3"
export suffix

find . -type f -name "*${suffix}" ! -name "*-*${suffix}" -exec bash -c 'modfn "$0" ${suffix}' {} +
```

The above bash script uses find to search in the current folder and it's contents for files like ***WWW_XXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_AAAAAABBBBBB-all.mp3*** yet excludes ones that are already renamed and look like ***WWW_XXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_20AAAAAA-BBBBBB-all.mp3***.

W,X,Y,A,B can be any character other than underscore or dash.

All the found files are renamed

NOTE: There are ways to shrink the above script but doing that makes the operation less obvious.

Comment: I have gotten the program to run and it does just as you said it would. well there are two issues. 1. it only does one file at a time. and second is that it does not play well with nested files. do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This perl one-liner does the job:

```
find . -name "XXX_XXXX_YYYYYYYYYY_*-all.mp3" -printf '%P\n' 2>/dev/null | perl -nle '$o=$_; s/_[0-9]{6}/_20100426-/; $n=$_; rename($o,$n)if!-e$n'
```

Note: I came just with a find command and regex part. The credit for a perl one liner goes to perlmonks user at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=823355

Comment: if i am seeing this one liner correctly it seems like the it only works of files with the name of that date _20100426. i don't think this will work for nested files that are of different dates.